# Gesture detector detects only the children inside the container and not the blank space in the container

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a container with a column as child and stack as immediate parent. onTap method only works when I press the Text widgets rendered inside the column widget and not the blank space of the container.

Comment: add some code we can try...

Comment: show structure of your widget